# use Cron to mail log from a job

Tags: 12.04, bash, cron, zfs

I have a weekly script that cron runs to make a zfs snapshot. I was wondering if it is possible to mail a OK mail if the job run correctly and a error mail if something happened and in the content of the mail to have the job log. How to do this?

```
25 11 * * 5 /home/aegrimisu/ZFS-autosnapshot.sh>>/home/aegrimisu/ZFS-WeeklySnapShot.log 2>&1 | mail -s "ZFS SnapShot Status" mymail@yahoo.com
```

The script content is :

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
zfs snapshot Misu@Misu-`date +%Y.%m.%d-%H:%m:%S`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`2>&1` tells the shell to redirect standard error to standard output. Without it, you would still get e-mails if the script printed anything on standard error.

This line from your `ZFS-autosnapshot.sh` script:

```
zfs snapshot Misu@Misu-`date +%Y.%m.%d-%H:%m:%S`
```

most probably gives you an error, so you must to use:

```
25 11 * * 5 /home/aegrimisu/ZFS-autosnapshot.sh>>/home/aegrimisu/ZFS-WeeklySnapShot.log \
            | mail -s "ZFS SnapShot Status" mymail@yahoo.com
```

as crontab if you want to receive the error by e-mail.

Answer (score 0):

**Variant with Mutt E-Mail Client**

1. Install mutt

   `sudo apt-get install mutt`
2. Create mailbck.sh and paste the lines from http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/5965821/
3. Make it executable

   `chmod +x mailbck.sh`
4. Adapt it for your needs